# Set width of the chart himself

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It's possible to set the width of the chart "area" ?

I mean not the whole chart only the part with curves.

Or maybe an other solution is to set the x-axis width.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can set for xAxis width that way:

```
xAxis: [{
    width: 200
}]
```

Comment: Well with this the chart is centered on the left and i want it on the right ^^.

Comment: So use marginLeft/marginRight, and spacingLeft/spacingRight.